# How can data about a Sites content in SharePoint be retrieved via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I would like to retrieve data from SharePoint regarding the contents of a certain directory via JavaScript.  For example: let's say I have a directory which points to a List of documents in my Department's Site.  Is there a way to retrieve data about this List of documents? An example of the data  I might be looking for includes the number of documents in the List.

To summarize: I am looking for a method to request data about how many documents exist in a certain directory in SharePoint using JavaScript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following options (and not only these) regarding to your possibilities and knowledge:

- SharePoint JavaScript object model ([JavaScript CSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx))
- [JavaScript REST calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798303.aspx)
- [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems)
- Your own jQuery calls of old fashion web service (ASMX) - [sample](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/querying-sharepoint-list-items-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Sharepoint Version. If you happen to have access to Sharepoint 2013 or later you should take a look at the JSON Rest Api.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx